# Command to clear the Git Bash screen, including output buffer

Tags: version-control, git-svn, git-bash

Is there any command in Git, that clear the screen. for example in window command line after execute a lot of code, if you type cls, then it will clear all the previous code. so i want the same type of functionality in Git. so can anybody will tell me the command name.

Comment: Are you asking about [clear(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clear)?

Comment: ok. i got it. i just type clear. it remove all the previous lines.

Comment: ctrl+l also usually works

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Actually you are looking for a Unix user environment command

```
clear
```

or you can use the keyboard shortcut

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clear_(Unix)

To clear entire command history in Git Bash.

```
history -c
```

Comment: Works under Windows, if you are running GIT Extensions (http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) and run a GIT Bash prompt.

Comment: should have been able to come up with that, gave up after clr

Comment: It does not work, it only moves everything up. It does not help to look through output lines after cleaning.

Comment: You might prefer to use `reset` so it gets rid of the buffer as well. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/123185)

Comment: When using `clear` multiple times, I've found that it only allows me to scroll back to the previous `clear`.  Is that the usual effect?  If so, is there a command that does `scroll-up-so-that-the-next-command-is-the-only-one-I-can-see-but-the-history-is-still-preserved-if-I-want-to-scroll-up-to-it?`.  PS Prize for most hyphenated string? ;)

Comment: This works, if you do ``history -c``` then clear everything is gone

Answer (score 53):

try using reset command, it will absolutely clean your screen but you will still have access to previous commands

```
reset
```

Comment: Nice! `clear` command simply moves your scrollbar in a fashion that you see a clear screen in front of you. So if you scroll up you can still see the output of the commands you had fired previously. `reset` command resets the screen scrollbar and flushes the output of all previous commands as well. So we can say `clear` command is soft clean and `reset` is hard clean :)

Comment: `reset` command reinitializes the terminal, as if it was reopened from scratch.

Comment: One way in which `reset` is **not** like reopening from scratch is that your current directory is retained. Also, the command history that gets carried over when you open a new Git Bash terminal completely from scratch is... somewhat wonky, particularly if you've opened several instances, closed *some* of them, then opened yet more new ones. If you do `reset`, then you know that the command history *in that particular instance* is still there. So yeah, `reset` is *exactly* what you want in most situations, and much better than "from scratch".

Comment: To put it simply: `reset` in Git Bash is the closest thing to `cls` in a Windows command prompt, which is what the question is asking for. So this is a much better answer than `clear`.

Answer (score 9):

Neither `clear` nor `history -c` does the work actually. 
**Scroll up**, all commands will be **visible**.

**Solution:**
If you are in Windows 10, and using mintty 2.7.9 (or above ?) for git bash, 
use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> ... this will work.

Best of luck.

Happy coding.

**Reference:** [here](https://github.com/Eugeny/terminus/issues/28) (Perhaps it didn't work for Windows 7)

Comment: Alt + F8 
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Neither clear nor history -c was clearing the history permanently.
All commands will be visible when scrolled up.
*So, I solved the issue by:*

*In my instance the path for **bash history** was:*
`/c/Users/<your_username>/.bash_history`

I removed the file by the following commands:

```
rm ~/.bash_history
```

After that, I restarted the terminal. the commands were gone.

Comment: Only this works.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 7):

CTRL + L

search for more shortcuts in: [here](https://gist.github.com/tuxfight3r/60051ac67c5f0445efee)

Comment: it doesn't work for permament removal of history

Answer (score 4):

Another option is modify (or create in your user folder) your .bash_profile and add this:

```
alias cls='clear';
```

With this you can clear the bash with a 'Windows' command.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment I use

```
clear;reset;clear
```

(in one line) and it sort of works (git version 2.32.0.windows.1).

Comment: it doesn't work for permament removal of history

Answer (score 0):

Most times clr, clear and cls doesn't work use ctrl c to continue writing commands

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 10 or above version then you can use the command

```
clear
```

Answer (score -4):

use clear only without git command

" clear "

Comment: This was already suggested in 2013. See the accepted answer. What's the point to send duplicate answers?