# How to make the input line on Git-bash not on the screen's bottom

Tags: git-bash

I am using `git-bash` on Windows.  I want to scroll past the bottom of the screen, so that there is empty space below the input line.  I prefer to look at the centre or top of the screen when typing commands.  Basically I want an equivalent to Matlab's `home` command, which makes all the visible text move upwards out of view, instead of clearing the text.

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704222/command-to-clear-the-git-bash-screen) which ask what is the equivalent of Window's `cls` command, except I do not want something exactly the same as `cls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clear` command, despite its name, will do this.

The `clear` command takes no input arguments.  It moves the old text upwards, instead of removing it like windows `cls` command does.

Comment: I am not sure why this is downvoted, even if the original question is a duplicate or in the wrong place, this is still a correct answer.